# Bash style: indent function defined with conditional?

Tags: bash, indentation

if one was to have a conditional control which version of a function is defined (rather than have the conditional in the function)

is there a universal agreement weather the functions should be indented?

```
if whatever; then
function myfunc() {
  echo "impl 1"
}
else
function myfunc() {
  echo "impl 2"
}
fi
```

vs

```
if whatever; then
  function myfunc() {
    echo "impl 1"
  }
else
  function myfunc() {
    echo "impl 2"
  }
fi
```

(only answer the question of indentation not on use of the keyword function, location of braces etc)

Comment: indentation makes it easier to read.

Comment: Experienced programmers always indent.

Comment: there are obvious exceptions to the rule, such as use of here-doc.  This is why I was seeking something definitive but only found plenty of disagreement about use of function keyword, how much to indent (2, vs 4, vs 8).  So far the one answer, as there is only one answer - is in the lead and while it makes an argument for a case it does not site a definitive source (the PEP8 of bash that I never heard of for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of opinion: yes, indent it.

As a more objective statement (and one that I am more comformable claiming to be a universal opinion): use the same indentation (or lack thereof) as you would use with any other statement in the body of a conditional. That is, write

```
if whatever; then
  function foo {
    ...
  }
fi

if whatever; then
  foo=3
fi
```

or

```
if whatever; then
function foo {
    ...
}
fi

if whatever; then
foo=3
fi
```

The rationale for this is that syntax aside, a function definition is just an assignment. Instead of assigning a string to a parameter name, it binds a compound command. In fact, even after the changes made after the ShellShock exploit was discovered, it is still possible to dynamically define a function in `bash` via an environment variable (mimicking the way `bash` itself exports a function defined the normal way):

```
$ env "BASH_FUNC_foo%%=() { echo 1; }" bash
$ foo
1
```

As such, there is little reason to treat it differently than any other assignment statement as far as indentation is concerned.

Comment: re: assignment - is it just a distinction between compiled and interpreted?  In C a function name is a symbol just like a variable name.  It just happens to be a read-only variable.